# Keyboard size changed event in swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, keyboard-events

I am aware of the keyboardWillShow and the keyboardWillHide events by:

```swift
override public func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }
```

But with the new keyboards in iOS8 the keyboard is able to change without dismissing the keyboard and I was wondering how to call a function on keyboard size change. Anyone know? Thanks.

Edit: It is now calling on frame change but using this code:

```swift
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
            NSLog("\(keyboardSize.height)")
        }
```

It returns the old keyboard height for example when the frame changes to "224.0" it returns "253.0" as if the height has not updated by time the code is called, and when it goes have to "253.0" it returns the old height again which is "224.0"

Edit 2:
Instead of using "UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey", I used "UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey" and it is now working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification and/or UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification.

See the [documentation of UIWindow](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/index.html) for all of the keyboard related notifications.

Comment: Works fine, but do you happen to know the answer to my updated question above?

Comment: Could you share your solution @uhfocuz?